# Problem trying to compile JLink application

Tags: java

I have no trouble compiling and running the sample Java to Mathematica program `SampleProgram.java` that can be found in the Wolfram installation:

```
FileNames["SampleProgram.java", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]
(* {"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.2/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/Examples/Part2/SampleProgram.java"} *)
```

When I try to compile and run a modified copy of this program from a different directory I get the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class files.wolfram
```

It seems it should be looking for `com.wolfram.jlink.*`.  I am quite sure the classpath to `JLink.jar` is correct.

Does `JLink.jar` contain a manifest pointing to some other resource that it cannot find?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That really sounds like a classpath issue even though you've checked it. If you don't modify the program and run it from the other location, does it work? Does the modified program work in the Wolfram directory tree? Are you having problems running `javac` (compiling) or `java` (running)? -- (no, there is no reference to `files.wolfram` in the manifest.)

Comment: @John Are you no longer interested in your question? I mean, why do you give a bounty on a question and then never show up to discuss your problem?

Comment: @halirutan I was trying to help a student with a project. The issue did not occur on the student's computer. So we have moved beyond this as an emergency issue.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you tell us exactly what you typed on the commandline, there is no way of knowing what went wrong.

Let me give you a head-start. My *Mathematica* installation is in the directory

```
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.2
```

Therefore, to start the `SampleProgram` I go into the directory where `SampleProgram.class` is and type

```
java -classpath \
  ".:/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.2/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar" \
  SampleProgram -linkmode launch -linkname 'math -mathlink'
```

and I get the following output

```
2 + 2 = 4
3 + 3 = 6
4 + 4 = 8
```

If you are working on Windows, then your command should look like

```
java -classpath ".;\path\to\JLink.jar" 
  SampleProgram -linkmode launch 
  -linkname "c:/program files/wolfram research/mathematica/8.0/mathkernel.exe"
```

Comment: This works on my computer also.  The problem arises when I try to move the SampleProgram.java to a directory outside the wolfram file tree.